How Vue3 @/v-on event function passing work?
<input type="file"
  id="fieldBoxContentAddPhoto"
  accept="image/png"
@input="inputPhoto(this,fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2,fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3)"
>

<img alt=""
  ref="fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2"
  src="fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3"
  style="width:150px;height:150px"
>

const fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2 = ref();
const fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3 = ref();

function inputPhoto(p,p2,p3){
  console.log(p);   //output is not the input element?
  console.log(p2);   //output the img element
  console.log(p3);   //output undefined?
}

1: In HTML oninput event passing 'this' will output the input element, how to do the same in @input?
2: How to output fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3 correctly, so that I can set 'p3.value = xxx;'? I know I can use 'p2.src = xxx;', but in some situations, I need to pass the ref to the function directly. Suppose I having many input+img elements in a page and need to call the same inputPhoto function for doing the same logic.

"v-on:click="handle('ok', $event)"", on here. Not sure about the other question, but you could store all of them in a variable. Or use a template ref depending on what you need. I am not sure to understand what is p, p2 and p3 honestly.

Oh nvm I understand now. this is the event object that you're receiving from Vue and that you could use to access the element in the same way as in HTML with $event.target. fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2 is indeed having the ref element as expected. You should not use fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3 in the inputPhoto function with p3.value = xxx but rather fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3.value directly and then use :src="fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3" on the img element. Call the inputPhoto and update the refs rather than trying to hack the DOM, this is not how Vue is supposed to work.

That is the point of the problem, if I have to use hard code 'fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3.value = xxx' in the function? If not, I can have a function that useable for many events, or write others global functions in project.

Make fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3 a dynamic value that could be generic and used in several places.

If you have many of them, use a component. Pass a param to the function to skip a hardcoded value.

Question 1 Solution: use 'event.target' to get the input element.
Question 2 Solution: Rather than passing params to function directly use reference and by using the '.value' property you can assign value. check below given example.
<template>
 <div>
   <input type="file" id="fieldBoxContentAddPhoto" accept="image/png" @input="inputPhoto">
   <img alt="" ref="fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2" :src="fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3" style="width:150px;height:150px">
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
  const fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2 = ref(null);
  const fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3 = ref('');

  function inputPhoto(event) {
    const inputElement = event.target;
    console.log(inputElement);
    console.log(fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2.value);
    console.log(fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3.value);

    const file = inputElement.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3.value = e.target.result; 
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
   }

   return {
    fieldBoxContentAddPhoto2,
    fieldBoxContentAddPhoto3,
    inputPhoto
   };
  }
};
</script>

